# How to validate a form in a bootstrap modal window in wicket?

Tags: forms, validation, wicket, bootstrap-modal

I'm searching for a solution to validate a small form in a modal window from bootstrap with wicket.

My dialog class derives from `de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.dialog.Modal`

Why do I use a modal window?

- I need to assemble a bigger object, which consists of different smaller parts. So this small form won't submit to database directly.

What do I have?

- Either I have a form, which submits the data to the underlying object. But the modal does not close, when I'm doing the error-handling.
  Here I need to close the modal by hand with javascript.
- Or I have a modal which closes on submit, but I don't see the form-validation.
  Here I need to suppress the submit-button attribute "data-dismiss='modal'" until the validation is finished.

Does anyone had similar problems and found a solution?

Update:
I use wicket validation.

Comment: I don't understand the use case. What do you use for validation? Wicket validation? Or JS, or HTML5? If it is Wicket then you need to override AjaxButton#onError(). There you can use modalWindow.close(target) to close it if this is what you need.

Comment: I use wicket validation. Your proposed solution works for the modalwindow -class which comes from wicket-extensions. But I use the wicket-bootstrap-modal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works for Wicket-Bootstrap too. What is the issue with it?

Comment: There is no "close"-function for the class 'Modal' or it's parentclasses (GenericPanel and higher).

Comment: hi, I'm just learning [wicket and bootstrap](http://wb-mgrigorov.rhcloud.com/). Can you give an example for using a Bootstrap `Modal` which contains a `Form` with a POJO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Modal#close(AjaxRequestTarget) to close the modal.

Here is its declaration:
https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/blob/484bab14c917ccb9ad520716b8b0e82e21a2d1e8/bootstrap-core/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/core/markup/html/bootstrap/dialog/Modal.java#L362

Comment: Hi martin-g, thank you, I just overlook that function. But somehow this closes only the dialog, the overlay from the background stays visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Now I got it. Obviously, I added to much stuff to the 'target'. With this the reference to the modal was lost.